# Firefox already running message while restarting browser

Tags: firefox, process, crash

I have an issue with firefox, after taking a particular web app and closing the browser. While i take the browser again on exit, it shows 'firefox already running' alert message. Unless i kill the process, the browser cant be opened again. In the web app we are doing a background process via AJAX for fetching certain contents. Is it because that these processes still run on background which prevents the browser from opening again.? Can any one suggest something in killing the background process on browser exit or a specific reason for this and a probable solution in this regard.

Comment: This is most probably not an issue caused by your web-app but an inherent issue in FF. I've run into it many times in the past. Often, you just need to give FF sometime to kill it's process. Your AJAX request has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Most of the time it is just FF needing some time to close. How long do you wait before you kill the process? Try disabling add-ons and see if that helps if you still have to kill the process. I doubt the AJAX request keeps the process alive.